# Tensorflow Prediction stucks at 50/50 and loss starts very high

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

My Predicts are always [0.5,0.5],my Weights are bouncing around, my loss startes ~30 and decreases slowly.

Model is conv->pool->conv->pool->fullrelu->full (softmax with logits later).

With TFLearn it works fine.

How I calculated loss(I mean its **sparse**_softmax, how could it go for 0.5 0.5, when sparse is for just a single truth label):

```
def calcLoss(logits,train_labels_node,WFully,BFully):
   loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
       labels=train_labels_node, logits=logits))
   return loss
```

How I calculated Optimizer:

```
def calcOptimizer(learning_rate,loss):
    return tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
```

Loss

[image]

Edit: After playing around with param and adding:

```
tf.train.create_global_step()

learningrate = tf.train.exponential_decay(
        0.01,                # Base learning rate.
        tf.train.get_global_step() * Constants.BATCH_SIZE,
        train_size,          # Decay step.
        0.95,                # Decay rate.
        staircase=True)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(..).minimize(loss, global_step= tf.train.get_global_step())
```

It works now.